# Exponent laws for rational numbers

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

this seems to be easy but I dont manage to prove it properly.

You are only allowed to use the following laws:
$$\left(z^m\right)^n=z^{m\cdot n}\quad \text{for $n,m\in \mathbb N$}$$
and
$$z=a^{\frac 1n}\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad z^n=a\quad\text{for }n\in \mathbb N. $$

Now prove that for all  $a,b\in \mathbb R$ and for all $m,n\in \mathbb N$ we have

$(a)\quad a^{\frac 1m}\cdot a^{\frac 1n}=a^{\frac 1m+\frac 1n}$

$(b)\quad \left(a^{\frac 1m}\right)^{\frac 1n}=a^{\frac 1m\cdot \frac 1n}$

$(c)\quad a^{\frac 1n}\cdot b^{\frac 1n}=(a\cdot b)^\frac 1n$

$(d)\quad (a^m)^{\frac 1n}=\left(a^{\frac 1n}\right)^m$

Do you know how to do these?

Comment: I am not sure this is possible if you don't allow distributivity of exponentiation over multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

b) $z=\left(a^{1/m}\right)^{1/n}\iff z^n=a^{1/m}\iff (z^n)^m=a\iff z^{nm}=a\iff z=a^{1/nm}$ and

$$\frac1{nm}=\frac1n\frac1m.$$

d) proceed as above up to $z^{nm}=a$, exchange $n,m$ and backtrack.

a), c) cannot be proven with only the two given rules.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one you would write

$$\left(a^{\frac{1}{m}}\cdot a^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{mn} = a^{\frac{1}{m}\cdot mn}\cdot a^{\frac{1}{n}\cdot mn} = a^{n}\cdot a^{m} = a^{n+m}.$$

Now try to compute

$$\left(a^{\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{mn}$$

and then use that $z = b^{\frac{1}{mn}}\Leftrightarrow z^{mn} =b$

Comment: Is $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ granted ?

Comment: I would think so otherwise you could prove it independently. $(ab)^1 = a\cdot b$. Then induction: $(ab)^{n} = (ab)^{(n-1)+1} = (ab)^{n-1}\cdot (ab) = (a^{n-1}\cdot b^{n-1})(ab) = (a^{n-1}\cdot a)\cdot(b^{n-1}\cdot b) = a^{n}\cdot b^n$. I would think that this is required to perform the proof

Comment: Mh, the question explicitly states what you can use. The first law could also be proved independently, by induction. IMO, we are stuck.

Comment: Yes maybe you are right but this is necessary to do the proof so then the question is ill-posed

Comment: Yes, I guess so. Waiting for the OP's reaction.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I guess it is allowed to use these laws. I don't think it's possible without these. And someone posed this question almost literally as I posted it above